# CSS border shape not aligning with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my border in line with my header/text however it is going off to the left?
(I'm a newbie to coding, have been doing it for about a week so I'm sure this is a simple fix, I keep getting somewhat close but never 100% correct)
essentially I just want it all to be centered...
The code I've written below (probably wrong)is producing this [replica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIBxN.png) for the text/background colour/border. I am trying to replicate similar to the design here [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IubUp.png)

```
#header-two-subheaders {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(230, 205, 186);
        border: 1px solid rgb(230, 205, 186);
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ; 
    }
```

thank you

I've tried playing around with padding and margin on both sides, just to add the image behind it is with display:block

Comment: If you use `position: absolute` the element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. Could you please share your code snippet to check the problem?

Comment: I'm also confused what you exactly trying to achieve here. What is `border` element in original image?

Comment: the border element was added originally so I could use as an outline for the shape - it should be removed. for the background image I've written the below code                
        .pampas {
        position:relative;
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
       }  then for the wording / background fill with border I wrote -            
    #header-two-subheaders {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    border-width: 50%;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(200, 179, 165, 40%);
        border-radius: 180px 180px 0px 0px ;  
    }    - is this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would change to position: relative; and use margin: 25% auto;

If the elements are setup in the html correctly that will center the box

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).